# Why am I getting "Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component" with my component?

Tags: react-native

I have a component called Home with the following code inside:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Text from "react-native-web/dist/exports/Text";

export default function Home (props) {
    return (
        <Text>{props.message}</Text>
    )
}
```

I’m importing this component in App.js like so:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Home from './components/Home'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: "Hello, world!"
    }
  }

  render (){
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Home message={this.state.message}/>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

When I run this code, I get an error message stating `Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo
You are importing from the wrong file u have to import it from react-native

Answer (score 0):

You are importing wrong Text component.

Instead of:

```
import Text from "react-native-web/dist/exports/Text";
```

Try:

```
import {Text} from "react-native";
```